# Intersystems Cache ObjectScript change property value during %Save()

Tags: validation, properties, save, intersystems-cache, objectscript

**Given:**

- A class named B.
- 2 persistent records of class B, id = {"B1", "B2"}.
- A class named A:

  ```
  class A Extends %Persistent
  {
   Property rB As B;
   ForeignKey FKB(rB) References B();
  }
  ```
- An instance of class A, named objA, with objA.rB = "B3" (which is an invalid value because B has no "B3" persistent record)

**I want that:**

When objA is going to be saved (objA.%Save()), substitute with an empty string the rB invalid value and save it.

**So far:**

I have tried to make the substitution using callback methods ( %OnBeforeSave), but it seems that %ValidateObject is being called before.

Is there a way of doing value changes before %ValidateObject using callback methods?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify objects in callback method %OnAddToSaveSet:
http://docs.intersystems.com/cache201511/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GOBJ_callbacks#GOBJ_cb_onaddtosaveset